# Can't use a method in another class C#

Tags: c#

I have created a new **Windows Forms** project and a new **class** file.
I wrote a new class with a **public modifier.**

When I edit **Program.cs** file and try to create a new object using that class, I don't find the class because is marks it on green but after the dot, it just don't give me the method.

Needless to say that I used the using statement in the beginning of the **Program.cs** to call the **namespace**.

What can be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class is not static, so you need  to instantiate it before you can access its methods.

Try the following:

```
public string Test()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.MyMethod();
}
```

Otherwise make your class static, like the following:

```
public static class StaticClass
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want use a method from another class. This method must to be static, but if you do not want to use static class, then you must create an instance of that class where this method is.